# how to fetch data from example.json file from react isomorphic fetch

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I have an item.json file in my react project folder which contains a list of items.

How to load the file and get the date using isomorphic fetch from react and sort the data in reverse alphabetical order?

The folder structure is:

```
|node modules
|public
|src
  |App.js
  |index.js
|package.json
|item.json
```

Comment: Which bundler are you using? Is it webpack?

Comment: yes iam using webpack . tell me with and without webpack please

Comment: You mentioned 3 different operations: a)"load the file" b)"use isomorphic fetch", c) sort.

Each of operation is simple,  but you must clarify:

a) do you want load file from filesystem 
b) or you want fetch data from service

Comment: I mean i need to fetch the data from the item.json  mentioned in folder structure. and sort the data in reverse alphabetical oder